# Key combinations (eg Ctrl+Alt+arrow) do not work with xmodmap remapping ijkl to arrows

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using xmodmap to remap `CapsLock` to `Mode_switch` and ijkl to get remapped to arrows. The only issue is that ijkl do not always behave as normal arrows.

Two examples: A) `Ctrl+Alt+Right` should switch to the desktop on the right; B) when searching in the menu for a program, down arrows should select the second item found. These functionalities do not work with `Mode_switch+ijkl`. I also went in the "Keyboard Shortcuts" to redefine the shortcut in A as `Ctrl+Alt+Mode_switch+l`, which shows `Ctrl+Alt+Right` as before. Is there any solution?

```
! Clear modifiers, so we can assign other things to them
clear lock
clear control
clear mod1
clear mod2
clear mod3
clear mod4
clear mod5
 
! CapsLock 66 is mode switch
keycode 66 = Mode_switch

! Add back the modifier keys approx as they were
add control = Control_L Control_R
add mod1 = Alt_L Alt_R Meta_L
add mod2 = Num_Lock
add mod4 = Super_L Super_R
add mod5 = Mode_switch ISO_Level3_Shift

! Mode_switch + hjkl is arrow keys
keycode 44 = j J Left Left numbersign numbersign
keycode 31 = i I Up Up i i
keycode 45 = k K Down Down k k
keycode 46 = l L Right Right l l
```